# 500 Internal Server Error on uploading the image

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiimage

I'm facing an issue to uploading an image to server. and getting `500 Internal Server Error`.

I'm uploading the image by below code

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request setPostValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"nickname"] forKey:@"nick"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img.image);
     [request addData:imageData withFileName:@"image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"image"];
    //[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"profileImage.jpeg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"image"];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestSuccess:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

and in response

```
-(void)requestSuccess:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request{
    NSLog(@"%@",[request responseData]);
    NSError *error;

    NSString* newStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request responseData]
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[request responseData] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

firstly there is an error on converting data `JSON` data to `NSdictionary`, and it through below error

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x8563f70 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

then I tried to check be converting `Response` data in nsstring as done above and by doing so I'm getting below string in response

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
 <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
 <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
 <p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.    Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
```

Should be:

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
```